# How do I create a Django Login in Wordpress?

Tags: django, wordpress, python-2.7

I have a Django website I also recently created a WordPress website to advertise the company. In the WordPress website, I created a custom login popup that makes the login request to Django gets the tokens and then redirects to the Django System. But when it gets to Django the cookies with tokens are not set and the user is requested to log in again. Any Idea why? Is there a configuration I should set?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

1. you can put your token in header rather than cookie
2. you can add cors header in http request and response which can help you pass cookie in different web, look this [django-cors-header](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers)